# Why doesn't parseFloat() fix NaN (Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, nan, parsefloat

EDIT: Here is a reproducible example. When complete, this program will take two points on the surface of a 510x510x510 cube and connect them by the shortest path.

```js
function getSign(a) { // Detects whether a number is positive, negative, or zero.
  if (a) {
    return a / Math.abs(a);
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}

function findFace(x, y, z) { // Detects which face of the cube a given set of coordinates is on. One input must be set to 255 or -255.
  var returnArray = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    if (Math.abs(arguments[i]) == 255) {
      returnArray.push((i + 1) * getSign(arguments[i]));
    }
  }
  return returnArray;
}

function matchFaces(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2) { // Detects whether two sets of coordinates are on the same face, adjacent faces, or opposite faces of the cube.
  var array1 = findFace(x1, y1, z1);
  var array2 = findFace(x2, y2, z2);
  var returnArray = new Array();
  var adj = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    if (array2.indexOf(array1[i]) > -1) {
      returnArray.push(array1[i]);
    } else if (array2.indexOf(0 - array1[i]) == -1) {
      adj = true;
    }
  }
  if (returnArray.length < 1) {
    returnArray.push(0);
  }
  if (adj) {
    for (i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
      returnArray.push(array1[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
      returnArray.push(array2[i]);
    }
  } else if (returnArray[0] == 0) {
    returnArray.push(0);
    returnArray.push(array1[0]);
  }
  return returnArray;
}

function buildPathSameFace(x1, y1, x2, y2, isPositive) { // Connects two points on the same face of the cube.
  var returnArray = new Array();
  var pathLength = Math.abs(x2 - x1);
  var pathWidth = Math.abs(y2 - y1);
var longStep = (getSign(x2 - x1)) * pathLength / Math.max(pathLength, pathWidth);
var shortStep = (getSign(y2 - y1)) * pathWidth / Math.max(pathLength, pathWidth);
var longSide = x1;
var shortSide = y1;
for (var i = 0; i < pathLength; i++) {
  returnArray.push([longSide, shortSide, 255 * (2 * isPositive - 1)]);
  longSide += longStep;
  shortSide += shortStep;
}
return returnArray;
}

function buildPathAdjFaces(x1, y1, y2, z2, posStart, posEnd) { // Connects two points on adjacent faces of the cube.
  var startLeg = 255 - x1 * getSign(x1) * (posEnd * 2 - 1);
  var endLeg = 255 - z2 * getSign(z2) * (posStart * 2 - 1);
  var pathLength = startLeg + endLeg;
  var pathWidth = Math.abs(y2 - y1);
  var hingePoint = y1 + pathWidth * startLeg / pathLength * getSign(y2 - y1);
  var returnArray = buildPathSameFace(x1, y1, 255 * posEnd, hingePoint, posStart);
  var endArray = buildPathSameFace(255 * (posStart * 2 - 1), hingePoint, z2, y2, posEnd);
  for (var i = 0; i < endArray.length; i++) {
    returnArray.push([endArray[i][2], endArray[i][1], endArray[i][0]]);
  }
  return returnArray;
}

function buildPathOppFaces(x1, y1, x2, y2, isPositive) { // Connects two points on opposite faces of the cube.
  var starts = [255 - x1, 255 + x1, 255 - y1, 255 + y1];
  var ends = [255 - x2, 255 + x2, 255 - y2, 255 + y2];
  var startLeg = 255;
  var endLeg = 255;
  var counter = -1;
  for (var i = 0; i < starts.length; i++) {
    if (Math.abs(starts[i]) + Math.abs(ends[i]) < startLeg + endLeg) {
      startLeg = Math.abs(starts[i]);
      endLeg = Math.abs(ends[i]);
      counter = i;
    }
  }
  var longSide = x1;
  var shortSide = y1;
  var goalLong = x2;
  var goalShort = y2;
  if (counter > 1) {
    longSide = y1;
    shortSide = x1;
    goalLong = y2;
    goalShort = x2;
  }
  var pathLength = startLeg + 510 + endLeg;
  var pathWidth = Math.abs(goalShort - shortSide);
  var hingeA = shortSide + pathWidth * startLeg / pathLength * getSign(goalShort - shortSide);
  var hingeB = goalShort - pathWidth * endLeg / pathLength * getSign(goalShort - shortSide);
  var returnArray = buildPathSameFace(longSide, shortSide, 255 * (1 - (counter % 2) * 2) * getSign(longSide), hingeA, isPositive);
  var transitArray = buildPathSameFace(255 * isPositive, hingeA, 0 - 255 * isPositive, hingeB, ((counter % 2 - 1) * getSign(longSide) + 1) / 2);
  for (i = 0; i < transitArray.length; i++) {
    returnArray.push(transitArray[i]);
  }
  var endArray = buildPathSameFace(255 * ((counter % 2) * 2 - 1) * getSign(longSide), hingeB, goalLong, goalShort, !isPositive);
  for (i = 0; i < endArray.length; i++) {
    returnArray.push(endArray[i]);
  }
  if (counter > 1) {
    var swappedArray = new Array();
    for (i = 0; i < returnArray.length; i++) {
      swappedArray.push([returnArray[i][1], returnArray[i][0], returnArray[i][2]]);
    }
    return swappedArray;
  } else {
    return returnArray;
  }
}

function sortXYZ(x, y, z, orderKey) { //    Sorts three numbers to a predetermined order.
  switch (orderKey) {
    case "abc":
      return [x, y, z];
      break;
    case "acb":
      return [x, z, y];
      break;
    case "bac":
      return [y, x, z];
      break;
    case "bca":
      return [y, z, x];
      break;
    case "cab":
      return [z, x, y];
      break;
    case "cba":
      return [z, y, x];
      break;
  }
}

function buildPath(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2) { // Detects which faces of the cube two points are on, and connects them by the appropriate path. Not completed.
  var returnArray = new Array();
  var faceMatch = matchFaces(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2);
  var orderKey = "";
  var posStart = -1;
  var posEnd = 2;
  if (faceMatch[0]) {
    switch (Math.abs(faceMatch[0])) {
      case 1:
        orderKey = "bca";
        break;
      case 2:
        orderKey = "acb";
        break;
      case 3:
        orderKey = "abc";
        break;
    }
    posStart = (getSign(faceMatch[0]) + 1) / 2;
  } else if (faceMatch[1]) {
    switch (Math.abs(faceMatch[1])) {
      case 1:
        orderKey = "a";
        if (Math.abs(faceMatch[2]) == 2) {
          orderKey += "bc";
        } else {
          orderKey += "cb";
        }
        break;
      case 2:
        orderKey = "b";
        if (Math.abs(faceMatch[2]) == 1) {
          orderKey += "ac";
        } else {
          orderKey += "ca";
        }
        break;
      case 3:
        orderKey = "c";
        if (Math.abs(faceMatch[2]) == 1) {
          orderKey += "ab";
        } else {
          orderKey += "ba";
        }
        break;
    }
    posStart = (getSign(faceMatch[1]) + 1) / 2;
    posEnd = (getSign(faceMatch[2]) + 1) / 2;
  } else {
    switch (faceMatch[2]) {
      case 1:
        orderKey = "bca";
        break;
      case 2:
        orderKey = "acb";
        break;
      case 3:
        orderKey = "abc";
        break;
    }
    posStart = (getSign(faceMatch[2]) + 1) / 2;
  }
  var startSet = sortXYZ(x1, y1, z1, orderKey);
  var endSet = sortXYZ(x2, y2, z2, orderKey);
  for (i = 0; i < startSet.length; i++) {
    startSet[i] = parseFloat(startSet[i]);
    endSet[i] = parseFloat(endSet[i]);
  }
  if (faceMatch[0]) {
    returnArray = buildPathSameFace(startSet[0], startSet[1], startSet[2], posStart);
  } else if (faceMatch[1]) {
    returnArray = buildPathAdjFaces(startSet[0], startSet[1], startSet[2], posStart, posEnd);
  } else {
    returnArray = buildPathOppFaces(startSet[0], startSet[1], startSet[2], posStart);
  } // Another round of sorting needs to be done before the function is complete, but there's no point until the NaN problem is fixed.
  return returnArray;
}
alert(buildPath(161, 255, 180, -255, -130, 107));
```

This code produces NaN errors where there should be numerical output:
`myArray = myFunction(x[0],x[1],x[2]);`
So I changed it to
`myArray = myFunction(parseFloat(x[0]),parseFloat(x[1]),parseFloat(x[2]));`
with no effect on the output.

I wrote an alert before this line to see which parameter was the problem:

```
alert(isNan(x[0])+isNaN(x[1])+isNaN(x[2]));
myArray = myFunction(parseFloat(x[0]),parseFloat(x[1]),parseFloat(x[2]));
```

which gave me an alert saying "falsefalsefalse".
The function which generates the array I'm here calling x[] reads

```
function sortXYZ (x,y,z,orderKey) {
    switch(orderKey) {
        case "abc" : return [x,y,z]; break;
        case "acb" : return [x,z,y]; break;
        case "bac" : return [y,x,z]; break;
        case "bca" : return [y,z,x]; break;
        case "cab" : return [z,x,y]; break;
        case "cba" : return [z,y,x]; break;
    }
}
```

So I changed it to

```
function sortXYZ (x,y,z,orderKey) {
    alert(isNaN(x)+""+isNaN(y)+""+isNaN(z));
    switch(orderKey) {
        case "abc" : return [parseFloat(x),parseFloat(y),parseFloat(z)]; break;
        case "acb" : return [parseFloat(x),parseFloat(z),parseFloat(y)]; break;
        case "bac" : return [parseFloat(y),parseFloat(x),parseFloat(z)]; break;
        case "bca" : return [parseFloat(y),parseFloat(z),parseFloat(x)]; break;
        case "cab" : return [parseFloat(z),parseFloat(x),parseFloat(y)]; break;
        case "cba" : return [parseFloat(z),parseFloat(y),parseFloat(x)]; break;
    }
}
```

which gives me another alert saying "falsefalsefalse", and still outputs NaN instead of numbers.

Not *all* the outputs that ought to be numerical have turned into NaN, just some of them; I have yet to find any rhyme or reason as to which ones.

What do I do?

Comment: What is the **actual** runtime value of `x`, `y`, and `z`? I recommend you learn about _preconditions_ and imlpement them as assertions in your program, and consider using TypeScript.

Comment: I wrote an alert to show me these too. In my test case they were: 255,140.8904109589041,-161.84931506849315
These are generated by a series of calculations from purely numerical inputs.

Comment: You don't provide `orderKey` as argument and so it is undefined, and none of the cases are executed, returning undefined.

Comment: Is `myFunction` actually `sortXYZ`? If not, what's the relationship between them? Separately, please update the question with a [mre], including sample data that, when fed into the code, will cause the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: I tried to give a reproducible example but it's too long for these comments.

Comment: @DanielCopeland, you can edit your question to add your reproductible example.

Comment: I have edited the question to give a reproducible example. This code still produces the NaN error. I would still like to know what to do about it.